# Risk for information not being transmitted when connecting to an evil twin wi-fi spot

Tags: wifi

If I connect to an evil twin wi-fi hotspot, aka rogue AP, among other names, are only the data being transmitted at risk, or, are the data on my HD also vulnerable?

I am working with Windows 8, updated.

Answer (score 1):

Your whole machine is at risk.

The AP can see your network traffic, and also modify it. A typical attack would then modify a page you are accessing to insert malware as an attempt to take over your computer. If you have all updates, AV is enabled, and you click carefully, then the risk is reduced, but advanced malware could still get you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have public shared folders enabled then other people on your local network may be able to read or write some data on your hard drive. You can find out more about shared folders from [here.](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-8-file-sharing-share-users-system-folders-on-network/)

Besides things you have explicitly shared, there is no way for an external machine to read data from your hard drive under normal circumstances. Normal circumstances being that there is no software bug an attacker could leverage or malicious software running on your machine.

Data being sent may be at risk if it is not encrypted. When accessing websites that begin with https then your traffic will be safe from a malicious router.